# How Divide BigDecimal value in ireport expression with validation

Tags: java, jasper-reports, bigdecimal

I have this expression in field:

```
$F{quartoAptoValorTotalLiberado} != new BigDecimal(0) &&
$F{quartoAptoValorTotalCobrado} != new BigDecimal(0)   ?

$F{quartoAptoValorTotalLiberado}.divide($F{quartoAptoValorTotalCobrado}, new MathContext(100))

:
new BigDecimal(0)
```

All fields defined have BigDecimal type.

I am using ireport version 3.0.0

When I use ireport, the compilation is successfully, but when I compile in java run debug I receive an error because this expression is incorrect.

**I Can't reopened this question.
I was solved programmatically inside iReport 3.0.0 with this code:**

```
$F{dayClinicValorTotalLiberado} != BigDecimal.ZERO &&
$F{dayClinicValorTotalCobrado} != BigDecimal.ZERO    ?

$F{dayClinicValorTotalLiberado}.divide($F{dayClinicValorTotalCobrado}, new MathContext(100))

:

BigDecimal.ZERO
```

Comment: Side note: use [`BigDecimal.ZERO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ZERO)

Comment: Don't compare BigDecimal values using `!=, ==`. Use the [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo-java.math.BigDecimal-)method.

Comment: Thank You @JuanCarlosMendoza

Comment: How i sum values without use detail band? i need sum many fields of type BigDecimal